# Get table and column "owning" a sequence

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I can run the following line:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seqName OWNED BY table.id;
```

How can I get the 'owner' set by `OWNED BY` for a sequence (in this case: `table.id`)?

Comment: Upon re-reading the question, I understand now that you want to get the **table and column "owning" the sequence**, rather than the role "owning" it. I edited the title accordingly. Please roll back if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Get the "owning" table and column

> ```
> ALTER SEQUENCE seqName OWNED BY table.id;
> ```

Your `ALTER SEQUENCE` statement causes an entry in the system catalog [`pg_depend`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-depend.html) with the dependency type (`deptype`) *'a'* and a `refobjsubid` greater than *0*, pointing to the attribute number (`attnum`) in `pg_attribute`. With that knowledge you can devise a simple query:

```sql
SELECT d.refobjid::regclass, a.attname
FROM   pg_depend    d
JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = d.refobjid
                     AND a.attnum   = d.refobjsubid
WHERE  d.objid = 'public."seqName"'::regclass  -- your sequence here
AND    d.refobjsubid > 0
AND    d.classid = 'pg_class'::regclass;
```

- Double quotes (`""`) are only needed for otherwise illegal names (mixed case, reserved words, ...).
- No need to assert that `refclassid` is of type `regclass` since the join to `pg_attribute` does that automatically.
  No need to assert that the sequence is a sequence since schema-qualified object names are unique across the database.
  No need to join to `pg_class` or `pg_namespace` at all.
- The schema name is only needed to disambiguate or if it's not in the `search_path`.
  The same table name (or sequence name for that matter) can be used in multiple schemas. A cast to the [object identifier type `regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) observes the current `search_path` to pick the best match if you omit the schema qualification. If the table is not visible, you get an error message.
- What's more, a `regclass` type is displayed as `text` to the user automatically. (If not, cast to `text`.) The schema-name is prepended automatically where necessary to be unambiguous in your session.

#### Get the actual "owner" (the role)

To get the role owning a specific sequence, as requested:

```sql
SELECT c.relname, u.usename 
FROM   pg_class c
JOIN   pg_user  u ON u.usesysid  = c.relowner
WHERE  c.oid = '"seqName"'::regclass;  -- your sequence here
```

Comment: Same as previous comment. @PavelStehule if you have PostGIS in your database there is dependencies store in `pg_depend` and `pg_class` contains `relkind = 'i'` for spatial index. I fix this query with `INNER JOIN pg_class c
ON c.oid = d.objid AND c.relkind = 'S'`

Comment: in fact I don't understrand why `pg_namespace` and `pg_class` is not necessary because the objective can be set all sequences owner and if you are postgres user you are permission on pg_toast and it return result with this query

Comment: @GeoStoneMarten: Pavel's comment is already implemented by `AND    d.classid = 'pg_class'::regclass;` I didn't understand your second comment.

Comment: OK. it work fine only if you specify only one sequence. If I remove an element of where clause, there is others elements.  Not only sequence but fields use in spatial index or in pg_toast if namespace if not dismiss

Comment: @GeoStoneMarten: This question is about a single sequence. Consider starting a new question if you have a different case that needs a different solution. You can always reference this one for context.

Answer (score 18):

You may use following query:

```
select s.relname as seq, n.nspname as sch, t.relname as tab, a.attname as col
from pg_class s
  join pg_depend d on d.objid=s.oid and d.classid='pg_class'::regclass and d.refclassid='pg_class'::regclass
  join pg_class t on t.oid=d.refobjid
  join pg_namespace n on n.oid=t.relnamespace
  join pg_attribute a on a.attrelid=t.oid and a.attnum=d.refobjsubid
where s.relkind='S' and d.deptype='a'
```

It returns all sequences with owner information. Just filter them in WHERE clause and that's it.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to list the table and corresponding sequence for a particular column using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT   table_schema
       , table_name 
       , column_name
       , LTRIM(RTRIM(RTRIM(column_default, '::regclass)'),''''),'nextval(''') AS SEQUENCE_NAME
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE  column_default like '%nextval%';
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me, but i needed to add an extra LTRIM otherwise it would cut off the first letter of sequence name:

`SELECT   table_schema
       , table_name 
       , column_name
       , LTRIM(LTRIM(RTRIM(RTRIM(column_default, '::regclass)'),''''),'nextval('), '''') AS SEQUENCE_NAME
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE  column_default like '%nextval%'; 
`

Comment: Thank you this was the only answer here that worked!  There is an issue with my pg_depend table causing it to have some wrong dependency ids so the normal solution caused a major issue for me during my last migration.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c.relname,u.usename 
  FROM pg_class c, pg_user u
 WHERE c.relowner = u.usesysid and c.relkind = 'S'
   AND relnamespace IN (
    SELECT oid
      FROM pg_namespace
     WHERE nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
       AND nspname != 'information_schema'
    );
```

Comment: This works, because sequences "OWNED BY" a table must have the same owner as the table - according to the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altersequence.html).

Answer (score 0):

I use that query for get all queries.

Change CTE to filter the result

```
WITH table_with_sequence as (
SELECT
    d.refobjid::regclass::text tablename,
    c.relname::text sequencename,
    np.nspname::text schemaname,
    a.attname::text attname,
    u.usename::text
FROM
    pg_depend d
    INNER JOIN pg_class c ON c.oid = d.objid
        AND c.relkind = 'S'
    INNER JOIN pg_namespace np ON np.oid = c.relnamespace
        AND (np.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'
            AND np.nspname != 'information_schema')
        INNER JOIN pg_user u ON u.usesysid = c.relowner
        INNER JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = d.refobjid
            AND a.attnum = d.refobjsubid
)

SELECT
    'ALTER SEQUENCE '|| QUOTE_LITERAL(QUOTE_IDENT(schemaname) || '.' || QUOTE_IDENT(sequencename)) ||' OWNED BY ' || tablename || '.' || QUOTE_IDENT(attname)
FROM table_with_sequence
```