# Where to find object dependencies in Postgresql ? (pg_depend)

Tags: postgresql

In Postgresql 8.1.23, I want to know on which objects my table is depending.

I did :

```
SELECT * FROM pg_depend WHERE objid=
  (SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'prix_articleclient');
 classid |  objid  | objsubid | refclassid | refobjid | refobjsubid | deptype
---------+---------+----------+------------+----------+-------------+---------
    1259 | 5877366 |        0 |       2615 |    24605 |           0 | n
```

My question is : what is the object '24605'?
I searched in dozens of tables, webpages, forums, including stackoverflow, but was not able to find any help.

Any help will therefore be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Note that I tried "\d+ your_table" and "[Find dependent objects for a table or view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462908/find-dependent-objects-for-a-table-or-view)" without success

P.P.S. I also tried that, but it seems to lead to nowhere :

```
# SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 2615 ;
   relname    | relnamespace | reltype | relowner | relam | relfilenode | reltablespace | relpages | reltuples | reltoastrelid | reltoastidxid | relhasindex | relisshared | relkind | relnatts | relchecks | reltriggers | relukeys | relfkeys | relrefs | relhasoids | relhaspkey | relhasrules | relhassubclass |    relacl
 pg_namespace |           11 |   10275 |       10 |     0 |        2615 |             0 |        1 |         5 |             0 |             0 | t           | f           | r       |        3 |         0 |           0 |        0 |        0 |       0 | t          | f          | f           | f              | {=r/postgres}

# SELECT * FROM pg_type WHERE oid=10275;
   typname    | typnamespace | typowner | typlen | typbyval | typtype | typisdefined | typdelim | typrelid | typelem | typinput  | typoutput  | typreceive  |   typsend   | typanalyze | typalign | typstorage | typnotnull | typbasetype | typtypmod | typndims | typdefaultbin | typdefault
 pg_namespace |           11 |       10 |     -1 | f        | c       | t            | ,        |     2615 |       0 | record_in | record_out | record_recv | record_send | -          | d        | x          | f          |           0 |        -1 |        0 |               |
```

P.P.P.S. As suggested by Erwin Brandstetter :

```
SELECT *, refclassid::regclass AS referenced_class FROM pg_depend
WHERE objid = 'prix_articleclient'::regclass;"
```

gives this result :

```
 classid |  objid  | objsubid | refclassid | refobjid | refobjsubid | deptype | referenced_class
---------+---------+----------+------------+----------+-------------+---------+------------------
    1259 | 5877366 |        0 |       2615 |    24605 |           0 | n       | pg_namespace
```

And then :

```
SELECT * FROM pg_namespace WHERE oid = 24605;
```

...returns the schema.

Which means this dependency was the schema.

Comment: `Postgresql 8.1.23`? Seriously? Or do you mean 9.1?

Comment: Yes, "Welcome to psql 8.1.23, the PostgreSQL interactive terminal."
In fact we are migrating our database to a newer version, but the upper problem need to be solved first, because some sequences are not included in the dump....

Comment: OK, that's the version of psql. What do you get for `SELECT version();`?

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.1.23 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)

Comment: Our original problem is more or less explained on the post below, that's why I need to dig into pg_depend : http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/0684jtqmm9/pg-dump-sequence-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [manual for 8.1 (!)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/catalog-pg-depend.html):

> refobjid  oid     any OID column  The OID of the specific referenced object

You have to interpret that in combinatioin with:

> refclassid    oid     pg_class.oid    The OID of the system catalog the
>   referenced object is in

A shortcut to find out about that is the cast to `regclass`:

```
SELECT *, refclassid::regclass AS referenced_class
FROM   pg_depend
WHERE  objid = 'prix_articleclient'::regclass
```

#### Underlying problem

The underlying [problem described to your link](http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/0684jtqmm9/pg-dump-sequence-problem) is probably that the sequences are not *owned* by their respective columns. More details:

- [Get table and column "owning" a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941043/get-table-and-column-owning-a-sequence/17645177#17645177)

But why beat on a dead horse?
[PostgreSQL 8.1 is just too old. EOL 2010. Upgrade to a current version.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

Comment: Just to be sure, this is a more elegant way to do it, right ?
Because when I do it, I get the same result as above.
Is that right or am I missing some point ?

Comment: @DenisBUCHER: That means the entry in `pg_depend` is pointing to the catalog table `pg_namespace`, which holds schemas. Look for the schema with `SELECT * FROM pg_namespace WHERE oid = 2615`.

Comment: By the way, yes, I agree with you. We came on this problem while trying to dump the database to move it to a new version.

Comment: Strangely "SELECT * FROM pg_namespace WHERE oid = 2615" return nothing (0 row).

Comment: But SELECT * FROM pg_namespace WHERE oid = 24605; returns the schema, you're right.

Comment: I took the number from the comment before and must have picked the wrong column. `oid = 24605` is right according to the added output in the Q.

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much, I will follow the link you provided.