# How to correctly associate an id generator sequence with a table

Tags: postgresql, grails, database-design

I'm using Grails 3.0.7 and Postgres 9.2. I'm very new to Postgres, so this may be a dumb question. How do I correctly associate an id generator sequence with a table? I read somewhere that if you create a table with an id column that has a `serial` datatype, then it will automatically create a sequence for that table.

However, the column seems to be created with a type of `bigint`. How do I get Grails to create the column with a `bigserial` datatype, and will this even solve my problem? What if I want one sequence per table? I'm just not sure how to go about setting this up because I've never really used Postgres in the past.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580807/hibernate-postgresql-with-grails/7581050#7581050

Comment: I've done that. I have no problem getting the sequences to generate. The issue seems to be that grails is associating a bigint datatype with the column rather than a bigserial when creating the table, so the sequence does not get used properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Postgres 10** or later consider an **`IDENTITY`** column instead. See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517)

---

> However, the column seems to be created with a type of `bigint`. How do
> I get Grails to create the column with a `bigserial` datatype, and will
> this even solve my problem?

That's expected behavior. Define the column as `bigserial`, **that's all** you have to do. The Postgres ***pseudo*** data types [`smallserial`, `serial` and `bigserial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) create a `smallint`, `int` or `bigint` column respectively, and attach a dedicated sequence. The manual:

> The data types `smallserial`, `serial` and `bigserial` are not true types,
> but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier
> columns (similar to the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property supported by some
> other databases). In the current implementation, specifying:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>     colname SERIAL
> );
> ```
>
> is equivalent to specifying:
>
> ```
> CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>     colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
> );
> ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
> ```

Big quote, I couldn't describe it any better than the manual.

Related:

- [Get table and column "owning" a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941043/get-table-and-column-owning-a-sequence/17645177#17645177)
- [Safely rename tables using serial primary key columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-and-cleanly-rename-tables-that-use-serial-primary-key-columns-in-postgres/14651788#14651788)

Comment: Hmm, ok, so perhaps something is wrong with my Grails project setup then, because the id column does not end up owning the corresponding sequence. I thought maybe it was just something Postgres related because I have next to 0 experience with Postgres.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a generator in a domain class like this:

```
static mapping = {
    id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'domain_sq']
}
```

If the sequence is already present in the database then you'll need to name it in the `params`.

There are other properties also available as outlined in the [documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html), for example:

```
static mapping = {
 id column: 'book_id', type: 'integer'
}
```