# How make a complete CREATE TABLE script

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table, pgadmin, postgresql-9.5

In pgAdmin when you create a new script for your table `SCRIPTS | CREATE scripts`

You get something like

```
CREATE TABLE public.merchant_tracker_avl
(
  avl_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('merchant_tracker_avl_avl_id_seq'::regclass),
  x_lat numeric(10,6) NOT NULL,
  y_long numeric(10,6) NOT NULL,
  event_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT merchant_tracker_avl_pk PRIMARY KEY (avl_id)
);
```

The problem is in the other server where I try to create the table the sequence doesnt exist.

So I have to manually change the script to...

```
CREATE TABLE public.merchant_tracker_avl
(
  avl_id serial NOT NULL,
  ....
```

And that script generate the table and the sequence.

So how I can make the pgAdmin generate the correct script, so doesnt have to do that kind of manual changes?

Comment: what version of pgadmin are you using?

Comment: @maahl version `1.22.1` came with postgres-9.5

Comment: Maybe you should try [upgrading to version 1.1](https://www.pgadmin.org) (the authors of pgAdmin don't seem to understand how version numbers work...)

Comment: @IMSoP Looks like 1.1 is for `pgAdmin 4`, I have `pgAdmin 3` can you try creating a script for a serial field and let me know if give the correct script? I dont want make the change if doesnt fix it.

Comment: Yeah, I was being mildly pedantic, because I think it's ridiculous that they're not called 3.22.1 and 4.1, respectively. But I thought it might be worth installing and seeing if you got different behaviour (I imagine you can just install both side-by-side, they're just desktop client apps, not bound to the server in any way).

Answer (score 2):

The script you display is what you get if there is something different from an actual `serial` column. A `serial` is not an actual data type, [just a convenient syntax shorthand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517).

pgAdmin *does* reverse-engineer the SQL DDL code with a `serial` if all criteria are met.

Typically it's not `OWNED` by the column - which you can repair with:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE merchant_tracker_avl_avl_id_seq
OWNED BY public.merchant_tracker_avl.avl_id;
```

Related:

- [Get table and column "owning" a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941043/get-table-and-column-owning-a-sequence/17645177#17645177)
- [Safely and cleanly rename tables that use serial primary key columns in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-and-cleanly-rename-tables-that-use-serial-primary-key-columns-in-postgres/14651788#14651788)

Comment: You put same link twice. Not sure if double `control-v` or copy the wrong link.

Comment: That mean pgAdmin do the reverse-engineer on only one direction?. The problem is I want the script so I can create the table in other db. Of course I can create the sequence myself, but we all know what happen when you do things manually :(

Comment: You can fix the source DB, you can fix the SQL script, or you can fix the target DB. Your choice. pgAdmin just displays what it finds. Read the detailed description in the linked answer: 
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649682/safely-and-cleanly-rename-tables-that-use-serial-primary-key-columns-in-postgres/14651788#14651788